# Change innerHTML based on attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Somewhere in my HTML page i have a paragraph: `<p switch-type="label-on-off"></p>`

How can i change the HTML with a document.?.innerHTML statement based on the switch-type attribute?

Comment: That's not a valid HTML attribute. Either use a `data-` attribute, which is intended to let you write whatever you like (e.g. `data-switch-type="..."`), or use CSS classes (e.g. `class="label-on-off"`) instead of custom attributes. And with that said, also don't set `innerHTML` on elements, find the elements that need updating, and then update their classes (using their `.classList`), set their text content (using `.textContent`), or change their child tree (using DOM functions like `appendChild`)

Comment: OK, but if i use data- attribute. How can i find the elements based on that attribute?

Comment: As a normal HTML attribute, the same way you find elements based on attribute: ```document.querySelectorAll(`[data-switch-type="whatever"]`)``` (and remember: that returns an HTMLCollection, which is array-like, but _not_ an array)

Comment: Okay and how can i select  based on multiple attributes? Because ```document.querySelectorAll(`[data-switch-type="whatever"], [data-switch-id="whatever"]`)``` doesn't work.

Comment: Oh no, we're not playing this game: if you have a more detailed question now, [update your post](/help/how-to-ask) and then mention you did that so that people can answer your now more-specific question. However, if you have a _different_ question now (which this looks like), don't ask people to answer that in a comment thread. Instead, you first _search the web and stackoverflow_ for the answer to that question, because that question is guaranteed to already have an answer. Remember: this is not a general help forum, and "comment threads" are the opposite of what makes SO work.

Comment: Ok, i understand it and have found it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

using querySelectorAll(), that returns a static NodeList

```
var p = document.querySelectorAll('[switch-type="label-on-off"]');
```

> more info see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

then:

```
p[0].innerText = "isaac newton";
```

But if you want to change the HTML inside `<p></p>`

```
p[0].innerHTML = "<span> ...  </span>";
```